# Mongoose group results by year and month

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

For the following schema (pseudo code).

```
var Post = {
     title: "",
     content: "",
     date: new Date()
}
```

I want to return results grouped by month & year, so something like so, again psuedo code:

```
 [
   { year: "2016", 
     month: "4", 
     results: [ 
         {_id: "1232", title: "foo", content: "bar", date: "Some date" }, 
         {_id: "1232", title: "foosdas", content: "barsdasda", date: "Some other date" } ] }
 ]
```

I've been trying aggregation with Mongoose this morning and that groups by the month and year just fine, It doesn't return the actual model objects though.

This is my current aggregate query

```
               Post
                .aggregate({
                    $group: {
                        _id : { year: { $year : "$date" }, month: { $month : "$date" }},
                    }
                })
                .exec(function (error, items) {
                    if (error) { return next(error); }

                    console.log(items);
                    res.append("x-count", count);
                    return res.json("Done");
                });
```

Comment: Can you put up where you got to and the original document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [accumulator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#accumulators) operators in your `$group` to define fields beyond `_id`.

In this case, you would use [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push) with the [`ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) system variable to accumulate the array of docs from each month:

```
Post.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id : { year: { $year : "$date" }, month: { $month : "$date" }},
        results: {$push: '$$ROOT'}
    }
}).exec(...
```

Comment: Thanks! After that i'm really thinking twice before using mongoose. What a big workaround to a basic functionality.

Answer (score -2):

you could try:

```
mongoose.model('yourCollection').find({year:'2016',month:'4'},function(err,results){
    //your code here
});
```